# Can a Mageknight that selected Time Shift as her Spellsword ability make as many attacks with Relentless Pursuit as she has Spell Points?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, class-feature, class, spheres-of-power

The [Mageknight](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/mageknight) has these abilities, relevant to the question:

> Relentless Pursuit (Requires Marked class feature)
>
> You may spend a spell point as a swift action to make a single manufactured or natural weapon attack against an enemy you have marked. This attack is made at your highest base attack bonus, and receives a circumstance bonus to damage equal to your mageknight level.

and

> Time Shift [Core]
>
> When using any ability gained through the mystic combat class feature, you may spend an extra spell point to decrease that ability’s required action by one step: standard actions become move actions, swift actions become free actions, etc. This cannot reduce an immediate action.

Finally, eliminate the cost of either one of them using the capstone:

> Spellsword
>
> At 20th level the mageknight may effortlessly combine magic and combat. Choose one mystic combat abilities that costs a spell point to use. You may use this ability without spending a spell point.

Now for 1 spell point the mageknight can make an attack at highest BAB as a free action.

Can this be used *ad nauseum* to make as many extra attacks in a single turn as the mageknight has spell points?

Comment: Maybe you can self-answer: Does the text have a rule like *When an effect reduces an action's required action by 1 or more steps, if that action is reduced to a free action, that action can be taken any number of times* or something?

Answer (score 1):

**It is entirely up to your GM**

The definition of a free action is fairly clear in the rules on page 181 of the Core Rulebook. "... *However, there are reasonable limits on what you can really do for free, as decided by the GM.*"

The Paizo RPG Core Rulebook FAQ has the question "How many free actions can I take in a round?"  The answer reproduces the rules on pages 181 and 188 of the Core Rulebook and concludes "In other words, the GM can allow more or fewer free actions as appropriate to the circumstances."

So I suggest you talk to your GM about it.  I would hope that your GM would allow at least two Relentless Pursuit attacks, otherwise there is no advantage to augmenting the ability with Time Shift, but given the +20 circumstance bonus on damage on each attack (for a 20th level Mageknight) I would not expect them to allow 20+ bonus attacks at highest BAB.

Comment: My concern is that despite the action needed to use it being changed, relentless pursuit *may* still be limited to once per round. In other words, just because an ability *now* takes a free action to use doesn't necessarily mean the underlying ability can be used any number (or even *[spell points]* number) of times.

Comment: It's hard to say since its 3rd party material and each production company has their own way of writing. SoP is usually pretty succinct, but it may have been intended as a once per turn thing or else that combo was missed and is unintentionally powerful. For instance, look at Mageknight's Invisibility which (since its not the spell) in *only* broken by "until you target a foe with an attack or magic".

Comment: @Ifusaso I dunno… the invisibility is *still* 1 round/level *or* that. My bigger concern would be that *until you target a foe with an attack or magic* isn't a thing (because it implies a declare step that *Pathfinder* lacks) and instead should be *after you make an attack or cast a spell that has as its target one or more foes*.  I don't, however, find *this* interaction particularly powerful—mageknight spell points are low (like, usually below 30) and this is a *level 20* character—so she *should* be doing the crazy, yet I don't know if *this* is the crazy she should be doing.

Comment: I think it needs GM oversight is all